# Pass Seleniun Auth Session to python requests

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to pass a session, which is generated through manual authentication with selenium, to a request using the requests python lib.

After authentication through my selenium bot I grab the cookies

```
cookiesArray = driver.get_cookies()
```

and put them in a dict

```
cookieDict = {}
for entry in cookiesArray:
  cookieDict[entry['name']] = entry['value']
```

and call the site, which needs to be authenticated

```
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, cookies=cookieDict)
```

unfortunately I get "Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]"

Is passing a session possible in general or am i on the wrong path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Requests, Selenium - passing cookies while logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087985/python-requests-selenium-passing-cookies-while-logging-in)

Comment: It helps, but how would that look the other way around? Creating the connection with the driver and pass the auth cookies to the driver?